# How to get the value of an XML element using Linq even when empty

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, linq-to-xml

Please excuse my stupidity, I tend to find the traversing XML overly complicated.

I am using ASP.NET in VB.

I have an XML document which contains all the details of staff in my company...

```
<staff>
    <staffName>Test Staff</staffName>
    <staffTitle>Slave</staffTitle>
    <staffDepartmentName>Finance</staffDepartmentName>
    <staffOffice>London</staffOffice>
    <staffEmail>t.staff@company.co.uk</staffEmail>
    <staffPhone>0207 123 456</staffPhone>
    <staffNotes>Working hours Mon to Thurs 9.15 - 5.15</staffNotes>
    <staffBio></staffBio>
</staff>
```

As you can see, some nodes do not always contain data for ever member of staff; only Directors have biographies.

I access the values like this...

```
For Each staff In ( _
    From matches In myXMLFile.Descendants("staff").Descendants("staffName") _
        Where matches.Nodes(0).ToString.ToLower.Contains(LCase(search)) _
        Order By matches.Value _
        Select matches)
    staffName = staff.Descendants("staffName").Nodes(0).ToString)
    staffTitle = staff.Descendants("staffTitle").Nodes(0).ToString)
    staffOffice = staff.Descendants("staffOffice").Nodes(0).ToString)
    staffEmail = staff.Descendants("staffEmail").Nodes(0).ToString)
    staffPhone = staff.Descendants("staffPhone").Nodes(0).ToString)
    staffNotes = staff.Descendants("staffNotes").Nodes(0).ToString)
    staffBio = staff.Descendants("staffBio").Nodes(0).ToString)

    ' Do something with that data...
Next
```

Once it gets to staffBio I get an error saying "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." obviously because that node does not exist.

My question is how can I assign the value to a variable even when it is empty without having to do a conditional check before each assignment?

Comment: I'm also interested in answer to this question....

Comment: Do you have a schema (.xsd file) for your xml document?

Comment: No but I will certainly look into it after your answer. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome! Visual Studio will create a schema for you. Just open an XML file and select Create Schema from the XML menu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, `myXMLFile.Descendants("staff").Descendants("staffName")` is redundant. Descendants returns all the elements at any level within an `XDocument` or `XElement`. So, `myXMLFile.Descendants("staffName")` would give the same result.

Second, you can just use the Element property and the Value property like this:

```
staffBio = staff.Element("staffBio").Value
```

`staff` will only have one `staffBio` element, so there's no need to use the Descendants property. `Value` is a string, so you don't need to call `Value.ToString`. If the element is empty, then Value will return an empty string, which is what you're looking for!

Third, there is a much better (and I believe more straight forward) way of doing this in VB.NET. Here's a console app that demonstrates how I would do this:

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim myXMLFile = <allStaff>
                        <staff>
                            <staffName>Test Staff</staffName>
                            <staffTitle>Slave</staffTitle>
                            <staffDepartmentName>Finance</staffDepartmentName>
                            <staffOffice>London</staffOffice>
                            <staffEmail>t.staff@battens.co.uk</staffEmail>
                            <staffPhone>0207 123 456</staffPhone>
                            <staffNotes>Working hours Mon to Thurs 9.15 - 5.15</staffNotes>
                            <staffBio></staffBio>
                        </staff>
                        <staff>
                            <staffName>Other Staff</staffName>
                            <staffTitle>Master</staffTitle>
                            <staffDepartmentName>IT</staffDepartmentName>
                            <staffOffice>Oxford</staffOffice>
                            <staffEmail>o.staff@battens.co.uk</staffEmail>
                            <staffPhone>0207 123 789</staffPhone>
                            <staffNotes></staffNotes>
                            <staffBio>Some guy.</staffBio>
                        </staff>
                    </allStaff>

    Dim search = "Test"

    Dim searchQuery = From staff In myXMLFile...<staff> _
                      Where staff.<staffName>.Value.Contains(search) _
                      Select si = New StaffInfo With {.Name = staff.<staffName>.Value, _
                                                      .Title = staff.<staffTitle>.Value, _
                                                      .Department = staff.<staffDepartmentName>.Value, _
                                                      .Office = staff.<staffOffice>.Value, _
                                                      .Email = staff.<staffEmail>.Value, _
                                                      .Phone = staff.<staffPhone>.Value, _
                                                      .Notes = staff.<staffNotes>.Value, _
                                                      .Bio = staff.<staffBio>.Value}

    For Each staff In searchQuery
        Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", staff.Name)
        Console.WriteLine("Title: {0}", staff.Title)
        Console.WriteLine("Department: {0}", staff.Department)
        Console.WriteLine("Office: {0}", staff.Office)
        Console.WriteLine("Email: {0}", staff.Email)
        Console.WriteLine("Phone: {0}", staff.Phone)
        Console.WriteLine("Notes: {0}", staff.Notes)
        Console.WriteLine("Bio: {0}", staff.Bio)
        Console.WriteLine()
    Next

    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub

Private Class StaffInfo

    Private _name As String
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return _name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _name = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _title As String
    Public Property Title() As String
        Get
            Return _title
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _title = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _department As String
    Public Property Department() As String
        Get
            Return _department
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _department = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _office As String
    Public Property Office() As String
        Get
            Return _office
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _office = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _email As String
    Public Property Email() As String
        Get
            Return _email
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _email = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _phone As String
    Public Property Phone() As String
        Get
            Return _phone
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _phone = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _notes As String
    Public Property Notes() As String
        Get
            Return _notes
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _notes = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _bio As String
    Public Property Bio() As String
        Get
            Return _bio
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _bio = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class

End Module
```

If you have a schema (.xsd file) for your XML, then you can import a reference to that xmlns to your VB source file, which will give you intellisense for writing your LINQ to XML queries.

(**Edit:** A quick way to create a schema is to open up an XML file in Visual Studio and choose Create Schema from the XML menu.)

For more information and help, please check out the ["How Do I" video series on LINQ by Beth Massi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb466226.aspx#linq).

Comment: @Yeodave: This is the best possible answer to your question. Extremely complete and utilizes Linq and objects very well.

Comment: Wow, that is awesome, cheers Dennis! It seems I still have a lot to learn.

Answer (score 0):

OK think this is how to do it.

```
...
staffBio = staff.Descendants("staffBio").ElementAtOrDefault(0).Value.ToString)
...
```

Using `.ElementAtOrDefault(0)` instead of `.Nodes(0)` just returns "" if it's empty or `<staffBio>whatever</staffBio>` if it is not.

.Value just returns the content of the tags like "whatever" in the example above.

Is this right? Can anyone see any problems with this?